# Problema com led em arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Programei para que quando o microfone captasse uma certa altura de decibéis ele apagasse o led, e assim que captasse novamente essa mesma altura de decibéis ela ligasse o led. Porém no momento em que ela atinge essa altura ela apaga, mas logo em seguida já liga novamente sem que seja atingida a altura necessária.

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32
#define DELAY_LOOP 500
#define SAMPLE_WINDOW 50

#define OLED_RESET -1
#define SCREEN_ADDRESS 0x3C
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

#define SENSOR_SOM_ANALOGICO 34
//intensidade do som
#define SENSOR_SOM_DIGITAL 32

#define LED_ORANGE 4
#define LED_YELLOW 15
#define LED_BLUE 2
int count_led = 0;
bool led_state = true;
bool led_apagada = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, SCREEN_ADDRESS)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    while (true)
      ;
  }

  display.display();
  delay(2000);

  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);

  pinMode(SENSOR_SOM_ANALOGICO, INPUT);
  pinMode(SENSOR_SOM_DIGITAL, INPUT);

  pinMode(LED_ORANGE, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_YELLOW, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BLUE, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (count_led == 0) {
    digitalWrite(LED_ORANGE, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_YELLOW, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, LOW);
    count_led = 1;
  } else if (count_led == 1) {
    digitalWrite(LED_ORANGE, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED_YELLOW, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, HIGH);
    count_led = 2;
  } else if (count_led == 2) {
    digitalWrite(LED_ORANGE, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_YELLOW, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, HIGH);
    count_led = 0;
  }

  unsigned long startMillis = millis();
  int valor_mic_analogico = 0;
  unsigned int signalMax = 0;
  unsigned int signalMin = 1024;
  unsigned int sample;
  while (millis() - startMillis < SAMPLE_WINDOW) {
    sample = analogRead(SENSOR_SOM_ANALOGICO);
    if (sample > signalMax) {
      signalMax = sample;
    } else if (sample < signalMin) {
      signalMin = sample;
    }
  }
  valor_mic_analogico = (signalMax + signalMin) / 2;

  int valor_mic_digital = digitalRead(SENSOR_SOM_DIGITAL);

  Serial.print("Analogico:");
  Serial.print(valor_mic_analogico);
  // Serial.print("; Digital:");
  // Serial.print(valor_mic_digital);
  Serial.println();

  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(5, 7);
  display.print("Analog.: ");
  display.print(valor_mic_analogico);
  // display.setCursor(5, 25);
  // display.print("Digital: ");
  // display.print(valor_mic_digital);
  display.display();

   if (!led_apagada && valor_mic_analogico >= 2015) {
    digitalWrite(LED_ORANGE, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED_YELLOW, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, LOW);
    led_state = false;
    led_apagada = true;
  } else if (led_apagada && valor_mic_analogico < 2015) {
    digitalWrite(LED_ORANGE, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_YELLOW, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_BLUE, HIGH);
    led_state = true;
    led_apagada = false;
  }

  delay(DELAY_LOOP);
}
```

Esperava que ao atingir o valor de 2015 ele apagasse e só ligasse só quando chegasse novamente a esse valor, porém ao chegar aos 2015 ele apaga e logo em seguida liga novamente.

Comment: [Queira editar sua pergunta original](/q/584253/70) conforme já orirentado lá. Para evitar duplicação de informações, os comentários foram desativados aqui, mas continuam disponíveis na pegunta original.